# send file from client to server using socket in c on linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm very new in C language and linux and English is not my mother language. Sorry for those in advance.
What I need to is to send `.avi` or `.mp4` files from a client to a server using socket on Linux. I can send the file from client to server but the video on the  server is not working.

When I try to play the video, I keep getting an error like "could not determine the type of stream". When I checked the original video on client, the size was 5,787,969 bytes but the size of the video transferred on server is 5,786,954 bytes. I think this is because of data loss when I transfer the file.

How do I fix this?

This is my code below:

#### Server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>     // read, write
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  // socket, bind, accept, open
#include <sys/socket.h> // socket, bind, listen, accept
#include <sys/stat.h>   // open
#include <fcntl.h>      // open
#include <errno.h>

#define PORT    5500
#define MAXBUF  1024

int main() {
    int server_sockfd;
    int client_sockfd;
    int des_fd; // file num
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;
    int client_len, read_len, file_read_len;    // length
    char buf[MAXBUF];

    int check_bind;
    client_len = sizeof(clientaddr);

    /* socket() */
    server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(server_sockfd == -1) {
        perror("socket error : ");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* bind() */
    bzero(&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port         = htons(PORT);

    if(bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) > 0) {
        perror("bind error : ");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* listen */
    if(listen(server_sockfd, 5) != 0) {
        perror("listen error : ");
    }

    while(1) {
        char file_name[MAXBUF]; // local val
        memset(buf, 0x00, MAXBUF);

        /* accept() */
        client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &client_len);
        printf("New Client Connect : %s\n", inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr));

        /* file name */
        read_len = read(client_sockfd, buf, MAXBUF);
        if(read_len > 0) {
            strcpy(file_name, buf);
            printf("%s > %s\n", inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr), file_name);
        } else {
            close(client_sockfd);
            break;
        }

        /* create file */

        des_fd = open(file_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0700);
        if(!des_fd) {
            perror("file open error : ");
            break;
        }   
        /* file save */
        while(1) {
            memset(buf, 0x00, MAXBUF);
            file_read_len = read(client_sockfd, buf, MAXBUF);
            write(des_fd, buf, file_read_len);
            if(file_read_len == EOF | file_read_len == 0) {
                printf("finish file\n");
                break;
            }


        }


        close(client_sockfd);
        close(des_fd);
    }
    close(server_sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PORT    5500
#define IP      "127.0.0.1"
#define MAXBUF  1024

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int     s;
    int         sourse_fd;
    char        buf[MAXBUF];
    int         file_name_len, read_len;
    /* socket() */
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(s == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("connect : ");
        printf("fail to connect.\n");
        close(s);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(buf, 0x00, MAXBUF);
    printf("write file name to send to the server:  ");
    scanf("%s", buf);

    printf(" > %s\n", buf);
    file_name_len = strlen(buf);

    send(s, buf, file_name_len, 0);
    sourse_fd = open(buf, O_RDONLY);
    if(!sourse_fd) {
        perror("Error : ");
        return 1;
    }

    while(1) {
        memset(buf, 0x00, MAXBUF);
        read_len = read(sourse_fd, buf, MAXBUF);
        send(s, buf, read_len, 0);
        if(read_len == 0) {
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about the [`sendfile`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) system call for the client. And for both the client and server, you need to check for errors *before* you use the returned value of `write`/`read` or `send`/`recv`.

Comment: By the way there is a bug when you send the file name from the client to the server. TCP is a *streaming* protocol (as indicated by the `SOCK_STREAM` name), which means data flows like a stream without message boundaries. That means when you send the file name, the server have no way of knowing when and where the name ends and the data of the file begins. Either you need to include some special separator, or the length of the file name.

Comment: On the server line `if(file_read_len == EOF | file_read_len == 0) {` you probably mean two pipes for a "or" - `||`. The bit munging it's doing could cause something to drop out early. Also suspicious is the fact that the difference in size appears very close to MAXBUF.

Comment: Also, are you saying the file on the server is *larger* than the file on the client? Then no it can't be any "data loss".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, I'm saying the file on the client is larger than the file on the server.

Comment: I would actually expect it to be larger on the server-side, because of how (and where) you check for receive errors or end of file.

Comment: gosh I'm so confused can you give me more hint? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Lastly a few nitpicks: You should really check for `write` errors when writing to the file in the server. And also note that `recv` doesn't really return `EOF` on error, it returns `-1` (which happens to be the same value, but it's semantically different, and using `EOF` makes it easy to confuse that condition with the check against the *actual* end of data with the `0` result).

Comment: The comment from @moopet is a very big hint.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what does 'the difference in size' mean? the size looks same for me. I mean it's each 1024 for MAXBUF on server and client

Comment: First, have you tried changing the code as pointed out by moopet and me? I.e. use *logical* or instead of bitwise or, and move the `write` call to after the `if`? What result do you get then? How about the problem with the file-name? Have you fixed that? (I suspect that is the actual culprit here, how many characters is the file name? Is it nine characters long?).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed EOF to -1, moved the write call to after the if and changed file name size to nine characters long but still get same error :(

Answer (score 0):

### In Server

Look at your "file save" while loop in **Server**:

```
/* file save */
while(1) {
    memset(buf, 0x00, MAXBUF);
    file_read_len = read(client_sockfd, buf, MAXBUF);
    write(des_fd, buf, file_read_len);
    if(file_read_len == EOF | file_read_len == 0) {
        printf("finish file\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of `file_read_len == EOF | file_read_len == 0` you should use only `file_read_len == 0`.
Still in **Server**, inside *open()* function that creates the file, I also recommend to change `0700` to `S_IRWXU & (~S_IXUSR)` __but_it_is_not_mandatory__. See `user@host:~$ man 2 open` for more details.

---

### In Client

In **Client** you only need to add "+ 1" in *strlen(buf)*:
`file_name_len = strlen(buf) + 1;`
That is because a string needs to end with a null byte. And *strlen()* returns the length of string minus the null byte at the end :-)

I also recommend you to use *argc* and *argv* to get arguments, look:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int how_many_files = argc - 1; /* '- 1' cause first arg is program name
                                    */
    int fd; /* file descriptor */
    int i; /* a counter */
    char buffer[10]; /* a buffer */

    for (i = 0; i < how_many_files; i++) {
        fd = open(argv[i + 1], O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1)
            continue;

        read(fd, buffer, 10);
        buffer[9] = '\0'; /* last byte of buffer needs to be null char*/
        printf("First 10 Bytes of the file is: %s\n",
               buffer);

        close(fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```